# Error in Creating Object Trying to Test Code

Tags: java, object

So I'm trying to test my code from the Item class from the InventoryTrackerInterface(main) class but when I try to create the object, it creates an error. I think this is because of the private method called Item(), how would I go about fixing this? I'm new to Java so please keep it simple, thanks! :)

```
public class InventoryTrackerInterface {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Item test = new Item(); // error here

        test.getName();

   }

}
```

.

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private String upc;


    private Item() {

    }

    public Item(String name, int quantity, double price, String upc) {

    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getUPC() {
        return upc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your constructor `private` ?

Comment: @Drew: Are you sure that default constructor is a good idea anyway? Since you have no setters and only getters in your class it will be impossible for you to set a name or anything else on an Item when you use `new Item()` to create the Item object. Maybe you should rather use your other constructor that allows you to set all values.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Item() {

    }
```

Change it to public as

```
public Item() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That method is called the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). It is invoked when you create an object through the `new` keyword. The `private` keyword is an [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). In your class you have a public constructor `public Item(String name, int quantity, double price, String upc)` which can be invoked using `Item test = new Item("test", 0,0,"upc");` for instance.

As you can see in the access control documentation you can only invoke a method / constructor from within a class itself if the access modifier is private. 
You could make that constructor public, but it is not very useful given your class definition. You have 4 private fields without any set methods, so if you would make `Item()` public you could create an instance, but you could never set its fields. on the other hand the constructor `public Item(String name, int quantity, double price, String upc)` does not contain any code. Normally you would initialize the fields there like this:

```
public Item(String name, int quantity, double price, String upc) {
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.upc = upc;
}
```

You would then invoke that constructor with the appropriate values to get a meaningful Item instance.